# when should i use '&' when overloading an operator?

Tags: c++

lets say I got a class A and I want to overload an operator, when should I use

```
A& operator+(const A& b)
  {
    A c;
    c.val = this->val + b.val
    return c;
  }
```

or

```
A operator+(const A& b)
  {
    A c;
    c.val = this->val + b.val
    return c;
  }
```

without the '&' thing?

Comment: If you are returning a reference to itself `return *this;` you'll want the return type to be `A&`.  If you are returning a local variable or local parameter variable, you'll want to return by value.

Comment: Using the result of your first version would be undefined behaviour, as you have returned a reference to an object that ceases to exist.

Comment: Handy reading: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: Important clarification: how well do you understand what the `&` represents?

Comment: When you're returning a reference, ask yourself "a reference to what?" In the case of `operator+`, your first version returns a reference to a local variable that immediately goes out of scope, invalidating that reference. That's no good. But sometimes "a reference to the calling object" or "a reference to an element in a container" or the like is a helpful thing to return.

Comment: There's nothing special about operator overloads; they just have funky names (and a "magical" transformation from operator syntax to function call). The same principles about not returning dangling references apply as anywhere else.

Comment: @user4581301 i think i dont understand it very well, sorry

Comment: @tbsnsa Then you're learing the language in a confusing order. You should learn what references are before attempting to understand operator overloading. This should be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/2079303

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about. Just take eerorika's advice otherwise you probably will be sorry.

Comment: @user4581301 yeah, i actually came up with this question when i wonder what is the "std::ostream& os" takes in "std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& obj)" and thats where i started to confused about this & thing, is cout are some kind of lvalue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when should i use '&' when overloading an operator?

You should use & on a type when ever you want that type to be a reference.

Typically, a reasonable rule of thumb is to do what the corresponding built-in operators do.  If the corresponding built-in operator is a prvalue, then return an object in your overload, and if the built-in operator is an lvalue, then return an lvalue reference.

For example, 1+2 is a prvalue expression, so following the described advice, you should return an object when overloading the binary operator+.

> ```
> A& operator+(const A& b)
>   {
>     A c;
>     c.val = this->val + b.val
>     return c;
>   }
> ```

This function returns a dangling reference. If the caller attempts to access the referred value, then the behaviour of the program will be undefined. Don't return a reference (nor pointer) to an automatic variable.